# Effects of switching from /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE to /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

What are the effects of switching from /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE to /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS? I have noticed my application (a qt GUI application) now doesn't work correctly in release mode. If I put the console back in it works fine. I have tried getting rid of any prints to console but I am still seeing issues. The program links to a .dll library that was originally a console application but became a dll later on, it has also had its subsystem changed to WINDOWS. Only when they are both on CONSOLE and a console is present does it work correctly/stably.

Comment: The primary difference is the signature of your application's entry point. I.e., instead of `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` (or their wide variants), you need `int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow);` (or its wide variant). (Posting as a comment because I don't know how QT fits into this.)

Comment: Hmm, no.  There are much better reasons why this causes your program to misbehave.  The heap allocations will be different, now exposing a latent heap corruption bug.